# Azure Devops Pipelines reverse stepList data type

Tags: arrays, sorting, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an infrastructure pipeline which among other things, spins up the various components of the infrastructure, tests them, then destroys them again. I've allowed the users of the pipeline to specify which components they with to deploy by having a steplist parameter they can edit at runtime:

```
parameters:
- name: components
  type: stepList
  default:
    - task: network
    - task: rds
    - task: ecs
```

This parameter is passed through to the deploy-and-test template, which then iterates through the stepList, deploying and testing the relevant components:

```
steps:
- ${{ each component in parameters.components }}:
  - task: Bash@3 # etc
```

However, when it's time to remove the test environment, it can only work if it removes them in the reverse order, due to Terraform state-file dependencies. This should be simple, as it just means reversing the stepList "array", but I just can't work out how to do it. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we cannot directly reverse the stepList data type in the pipelines. As a workaround, you can create and use another parameter:

```
parameters:
- name: reverseComponents
  type: stepList
  default:
    - task: ecs
    - task: rds
    - task: network
```

When you delete the test environment, you can use this parameter in the reverse order.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That is a good workaround which I've been using. When I hand this over to the support team I think they'll moan about the number of fields so I will keep looking for a reverse option. Hopefully it will be supported at some point.